# eclipse how to show package explorer in debug perspective

Tags: eclipse

The package explorer in eclipse only shows up on the Java tab (perspective) but i would like to show it in debug mode also. is there a way to do that? i can't find it in Windows->Show view in debug mode but it is there in java mode (actually, that's project explorer but it looks like the same thing)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can open it by selecting Window / Show view / Other... / Java / Package Explorer.